# SUM of Sales matching specific product code

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sales reporting workbook that I am building, my skills in excel are limited.

I have an overview sheet that pulls information in from my monthly sales sheets, I would like to add the sum of specific products from the monthly sheets to the overview sheet however I will need to pull in the price they were sold at as well since some of them do not a static price.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put the multiply result of  PRICE & QTY on the column (let's say G) then you can use the SUMIF. The reason why your formula didn't work is because you're not using (") on your VMR. here's the code:

```
=SUMIF(June!D:D,"VMR",June!G:G)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the monthly sheets contain a row for each sale, and that this contains both the product code and the price it sold at..

```
=SUMIF(ProductColumn, Product, PricesColumn)
```

Substituting the correct ranges for the ProductColumn and PricesColumn referencing your monthly sheet, and the Product code you want to sum for as the Product.

Comment: So what I ended up doing is:

=SUMIF(June!D:D,VMR,June!F:F)

VMR is the product code.  This is not pulling up any numbers from the sheet, but I also have an issue where the price of VMR might also have to be multiplied by the QTY in Column E